Does $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{xt}{1+x^2+t^2}e^{-x^2t^2}\cos x^2t^2 dt $converge uniformly in $ x\in (0,+\infty)$
When a parameterized infinite integral $\phi (x):=\int_0^{+\infty}f(x,t)dt ,x\in U$ converge uniformly , it means that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, there exist A s.t. $|\int_A^{+\infty}f(x,t)dt|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in U$. I want to determine whether $\phi(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{xt}{1+x^2+t^2}e^{-x^2t^2}\cos x^2t^2 dt $ converges uniformly when $x \in (0,+\infty)$.
After using Desmos to draw some graphs of the function, I believe that it should converge uniformly. So I'm trying to prove it.Define $$I(x,A):=\int_A^\infty \frac{xt}{1+x^2+t^2}e^{-x^2t^2}\cos x^2 t^2 dt=\frac{x}{2}\int_{x^2A^2}^\infty \frac{1}{t+x^2(x^2+1)}e^{-t}\cos t dt$$ The only thing I can prove is that the integral converges uniformly when $x\in[\delta,+\infty)$($\delta>0$)
($|\frac{x}{2}\int_{x^2A^2}^\infty \frac{1}{t+x^2(x^2+1)}e^{-t}\cos t dt|\le\frac{x}{2}\int_{x^2A^2}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2(x^2+1)}e^{-t}dt=\frac{1}{2x(x^2+1)}e^{-x^2A^2}\le\frac{1}{2\delta(\delta^2+1)}e^{-\delta^2A^2}$). If I fix A and let $x\to0+$, $I(x,A)\to0$(I believe that $I(x,A)\sim-x\log x(x^2+1)-x\log (1+A^2),x\to0+$ )
How can I prove that $$\limsup_{A\to +\infty}\sup_{x\in(0,+\infty)}|I(x,A)|=0$$
I have no idea how to do any evaluation or approximation.

Let $$f(x,t)={1\over 1+x^2+t^2}xte^{-x^2t^2}\cos(x^2t^2)$$ We have $$|xte^{-x^2t^2}\cos(t^2x^2)|\le xte^{-x^2t^2}\le {xt\over 1+x^2t^2}\le {1\over 2}$$ Thus
$$|f(x,t)|\le {1\over 2(1+x^2+t^2)}\le {1\over 2(1+t^2)}$$ Therefore the integrals $\int\limits_0^\infty f(x,t)\,dt $ are uniformly convergent.

For the pleasure of working an interesting integral.
$$I=\int\frac{xt}{1+x^2+t^2}e^{-x^2t^2}\cos (x^2t^2)\ dt$$
Let $t=\frac{\sqrt{u}}{x}$ and $\color{red}{a=x^2(x^2+1)}$ to make
$$I=\frac x 2 \int \frac{e^{-u} \cos (u)}{u+a} \,du$$ Using Euler representation of the cosine function
$$J=\int \frac{e^{-u} \cos (u)}{u+a} \,du$$ $$J=\frac 1 2 \Big( e^{(1+i) a} \,\text{Ei}(-(1+i) (u+a))+e^{(1-i) a}\, \text{Ei}(-(1-i) (u+a))\Big)$$
Back to $t$ and the bounds, the definite integral
$$K=\int_0^\infty\frac{xt}{1+x^2+t^2}e^{-x^2t^2}\cos (x^2t^2)\ dt$$
write
$$\frac K x=\frac{\pi }{2}   e^a  \sin (a)-\frac 1 4\Big(e^{(1+i) a}\, \text{Ei}(-(1+i) a)+e^{(1-i) a}\, \text{Ei}(-(1-i) a)  \Big)$$
Expanding the rhs for large values of $a$
$$\large\color{blue}{K=-\frac{x}{4 } \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n! \cos \left(\frac{3}{4} \pi(n+1)\right)}{a^{n+1}\,\sqrt{2^{n-1}}}}$$
Using $10$ terms for $x=5$ gives  $K=\color{red}{0.00192307239235859777305610}18$
Edit
For small values of $x$,
$$K=-\frac{1}{4}  (4 \log (x)+2 \gamma
   +\log (2))\,x-\frac{1}{8} (8 \log (x)-\pi +4 \gamma
   +2 \log (2))\,x^3+O(x^5)$$
Notice that $K$ is maximum $(K_{\text{max}}=0.257667)$  for $x=0.310804$

The expansion for $K$ is very close to a geometric series. What do you get if you sum that series up?

@Gary. The above is in fact the expansion of $\frac{(x-1) (x+1) \left(x^4+1\right)}{4 x^9}$

How about $\frac{1}{4x(x^2+1)}$?

@Gary. This is probably the simplest.

@Gary. Could we make something using the "blue" formula ?
